# Pulling a remote repo with a reserved character in filename

Tags: windows, git, git-pull

I'm trying to pull a remote repo from Github so I can push some new files afterwards, but one of my collaborators (who works on OSX) has named a file with a reserved character in Windows, ":". It's not necessary for me to pull the repo if I can push my changes without doing so and without causing potential problems (have looked into git pull --force but I'm concerned about potentially deleting files from the remote repo). What's the best way to go about doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could they replace the `':'`, which is Unicode U+002A, with another similar Unicode equivalent such as U+2236?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your repo up to completely ignore those files' existence with "[sparse checkout](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-read-tree.html#_sparse_checkout)":

```
cat <<\EOD >.git/info/sparse-checkout
*
!*:*
EOD
git config core.sparseCheckout true
git checkout
```

`git read-tree` implements the checkout and merge plumbing (checkout really being nothing more than special case of fast-forward merge), so that's where this is documented.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution may be the most low-tech: contact the person you are collaborating with, and ask them to rename the file.

It's certainly not elegant, but it is the safest way of dealing with the issue - and hopefully avoid similar issues in the future.